# Regular expression example in python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Test string S.
S must be of length, greater than or equal to 5.
First char is lowercase alphabet.
Second char is positive digit.
Third char is not lowercase alphabet.
Fourth char is not uppercase alphabet.
Fifth char is uppercase alphabet.

```
import re

Regex_Pattern = r"^[a-z][0-9][^a-z][^A-Z][A-Z]"

print(str(bool(re.search(Regex_Pattern, input()))).lower())
```

Why, using this piece of code, can't I match the string: `a0$?ZWe` to print `False` instead of printing `True`?

Comment: Why would it print `False` when it matches the regex?
Perhaps you meant to call `lower` on the `input` rather than on the result of `str(bool(...))` ?

Comment: Actually, I want that string to be `False` instead of `True`. I mean `a0$?ZWe` doesn't match. My mistake.

Comment: But it does match, unless you don't consider `0` to be a positive digit. In that case change `[0-9]` to `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` is not a positive digit, yet you are matching it in your regex.

Change `[0-9]` to `[1-9]`.